# Which process space do node.js' async calls live in?

Tags: node.js

When an http request hits node.js and node subsequently dispatches that request asynchronously, in whose process space does that work live (the work being done in the asynch call)?

Comment: Node only runs as a single process, so what other process could it be?

Comment: I might not have known that so you should probably answer in the form of a statement and not a question.  :)  Now that I understand that, why doesn't the fact that the calls live in the node.js process just create another bottleneck in that memory is eaten as a function of the amount of concurrent work?  Seems like the bottleneck that's avoided by node's event loop is now pushed elsewhere?  I must be misunderstanding something...

Comment: In what software is memory not eaten as a function as the amount of concurrent work? You must know what work to do, which means using memory proportional to the amount of work. What do you imagine a lower memory alternative would be? How would a multi-process system use less memory when it needs to know at least the same amount of information about the work, but must also now have the overhead of process state information?

Comment: Dan please assume I don't know the answer - I'm getting the sense that you feel these things should be so obvious to me that I'm an idiot.  In any case, if we're avoiding a bottleneck in taking http requests but then pushing the work into another bottleneck situation which as you said is not unique to node, then it's not clear to me why not just use a regular web server and let the clients wait until the other requests' blocking calls are finished?  How is the immediate acceptance and dispatching of the request by node solving that big of a problem?  You're gonna wait now or wait later.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you... an explanation of the benefits and tradeoffs in an event-based instead of thread-based server model would take more space than this comments box. Let's start with a link with a general description of the difference: http://code.danyork.com/2011/01/25/node-js-doctors-offices-and-fast-food-restaurants-understanding-event-driven-programming/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same process that accepted request (and same thread). All javascript code and event loop is executed in one tread. Some function calls are dispatched internally via thread pool but "userspace" (e.i your javascript code) always run in single thread